# Mips program doesnt print anything

Tags: assembly, mips

I have a program in MIPS assembly thats is supposed to swap a char in my message.

If the char is 'a', it swaps by the char 'b'.

So i have:"holla" and it must print "hollb".

There's what i have:

```
.data
string: .asciiz "holla"
a: .ascii "a"
a1: .ascii "b"
tam: .word 5

.text 

main:
lw $t6, tam #string length
lb $t1, string($t0) #read bit by bit

lb $s0, a #save in register the char that we want to search
lb $s1, a1 #save in register the char that we want to replace

beq $t0, $t6, done

beq $t1, $s0, continua #if the char of (bit by bit) its like the char of chars, swap it
bne $t1, $s0, store #if not, saves

continua:
sb $s1, string($t0) #do the swap 
addi $t0, $t0, 1 #+1 in the index
j main 

store:
    sb $t1, string($t0) #saves
    addi $t0, $t0, 1 #+1 in the index
    j main
done:
    li $v0, 4
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

But the code doesnt print me anything in mars.

Comment: Why _would_ it print anything? The only system call you execute is 10 (i.e. `exit`). Also, you're making assumptions about the initial value of `$t0` that you probably shouldn't be doing. Initialize all registers before using their values.

Answer (score 0):

You may have wrote `li $v0, 4` but this in not excaclty how print in MIPS works. Here's how it should have been:

```
li $v0, 4       # to print a string
la $a0, string  # load string's address
syscall
```

And then

```
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

to terminate the program.